# Consume Rest of Input Using cin C++

Tags: c++, string, input

I'm trying to consume the rest of an input on cin. Currently my function does this ...

```
void foo() {
    // Input "514 G Alex Thornton
    std::cin >> INT >> STD::STRING >> STD::STRING
}
```

So far the int variable consumes **514**, and the first string variable consumes **G**; however, that leaves the name remaining, which can be an infinite amount of words. Is there a way to consume the rest of the line?

Comment: You can use `std::getline ()` to read the rest.

Comment: How do I do that? I understand using

getLine(std::cin, VARIABLE)

But I want to split the input to other variables

Comment: You can do further splitting using `std::istringstream `.

Comment: @Xari read the  `std::cin >> INT >> STD::STRING;` and then further use `getline(std::cin, STD::STRING);`

Comment: My professor at the moment wants me to do without istringstream. And what do you mean Ahmed? Can I see an example? Cause that's what I did but it only consumes one part of the name "Alex"

Comment: Oh thank you! It hit me while I was writing. Getline will just consume up to the carriage return, right? Therefore getting the entire input.